# Best Way to Force Shiny to Trigger on Intial Load

Tags: r, shiny

I have the below code in my Shiny server. My intention is that every time the refreshData button on the UI is clicked, the database is queried, and this data is used in summaryPlot. Is there a way to also trigger the exact same database query when the Shiny app is first loaded up?

```
shinyServer(function(input, output, session){

  dailySummaryTable = eventReactive (input$refreshData,  {  
    temp = GetData(input$dateRange[1], input$dateRange[2])    
    return (temp)
  })  

  output$summaryPlot = renderPlot({

    summary = dailySummaryTable()

    ggplot(summary) + geom_bar(aes(x=as.factor(Class), y=Num, fill=Type), stat = 'identity')
  }) 
})
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You could add the argument `ignoreNull = FALSE` to the `eventReactive`. A working example is given below. Hope this helps!

```
shinyApp(ui,server)

library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton('refreshData','Refresh!'),
  tableOutput('summaryTable')
)

server <- function(input, output, session){

  df = eventReactive (input$refreshData, ignoreNULL = F, {  
    mtcars[sample(seq(nrow(mtcars)),5),]
  })  

  output$summaryTable = renderTable({
    head(df())
  }) 
}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

---

Compare this with the behavior of the app where the `ignoreNull` argument is not used:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton('refreshData','Refresh!'),
  tableOutput('summaryTable')
)

server <- function(input, output, session){

  df = eventReactive (input$refreshData, {  
    mtcars[sample(seq(nrow(mtcars)),5),]
  })  

  output$summaryTable = renderTable({
    head(df())
  }) 
}
```

Comment: you beat me to it :)

Comment: @maRmat sorry ;) You could undelete your answer IMO, it is a good answer, and it contains a useful reference.